# JWPlayer in tableview

Tags: ios, tableview, jwplayer

I am trying JWPlayer SDK for playing list of videos, but it seems like there is no way to use multiple instances of JWPlayer in the same view. I tried it with the default AVplayer list of videos and it works fine, but when I use JWPlayer, it does not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: at this point, the question cannot really be answered as you show no code of yours and the sdk is closed source and commercial and you cant even see the some header files ;) from their docs JWPlayerController should be able to be instantiated N times in parallel but I cant say. - id try to contact their support first

Comment: Thanks @Daij-Djan ,, You are right , but i didn't  provide code cause I was asking about the concept itself if its doable or not . Anyways I could work around this and it works now. Thanks again for your suggestion .

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this by adding instance to custom cell , then adding instance view  to cell view when table ends dragging . In finish display cell for row delegate method I remove the video view from custom cel view. It works.